# gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal error encountered.', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}

Tags: python-3.x, api, amazon-ec2, google-sheets-api, gspread

I know that this question is already asked but some don't have the adequate answers or some don't have answer at all.
solutions I tried

- time.sleep(5) stamp between every API call
- my spreadsheet does not contain any graphics just alpha numeric data
- checked the credentials for google spreadsheet API
  After trying above solutions my problem is still not resolved
  full error is.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/mytradingenv/A90_server_google_excel_bot.py", line 78, in <module>
    nsell_sheet.append_row([str(date.today()), str(current_time), banknifty, nifty, bn_pl, nif_pl, Sum])
  File "/home/ec2-user/mytradingenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 1622, in append_row
    table_range=table_range,
  File "/home/ec2-user/mytradingenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 1660, in append_rows
    return self.spreadsheet.values_append(range_label, params, body)
  File "/home/ec2-user/mytradingenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 189, in values_append
    r = self.client.request('post', url, params=params, json=body)
  File "/home/ec2-user/mytradingenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 76, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal error encountered.', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}
```

If you want to see my code for giving an appropriate answer please ask.

Comment: What is the line that gives this message? Do you get it every time? What is the request you send?

Comment: `nsell_sheet.append_row([str(date.today()), str(current_time), banknifty, nifty, bn_pl, nif_pl, Sum])` this is the line that is giving API errors and no it does not give API error every time i run the code i have been running this code for past 2 months but since last week it started giving API error and i am sending an row append request to gspread API